# form $_POST as an array

Tags: php

i noticed that when posting a form the fields come out as an array.

like if i do

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
print_r($_POST);
}
```

what i usually do for form fields is the following.

lets say i have something like this (this is how i usually do it)

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<label>First Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="fname">

<label>Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="lname">

<label>Phone: </label>
<input type="text" name="phone">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

then i'll have (im excluding field validation to make it look clear)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

mysql_query("insert into table(fname,lname,phone) values('$fname','$lname','$phone')");

header("Location: gosomewhere.php");

}
```

since the post outputs are in an array format how else can i write this when im dealing with over 100 fields?

how are the big guys doing it out there? or how are you doing it?

edit: the most ive dealth with is around 60 fields. im building this cms that takes in alot of data per form to put together information from a customer.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think I've ever seen anybody "dealing with over 100 fields" in a single form. If that is the case, you may consider a design-change that auto-saves portions of the data along the way. Form data will always submit itself into an array on the server-end, there's no way around this.

If you want to iterate over many fields all at once (suppose you are accepting multiple event-dates in your form), you could use the [array-style naming-convention](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays):

```
<input type="text" name="events[]" />
```

Once you access this data on the server end, you can iterate over it quickly in a simple loop:

```
foreach ($_POST["events"] as $event) {
  echo $event;
}
```

I'm sorry if I missunderstood your question.

Comment: its ok, the reason i asked this is because ive looked through 3rd party web applications and the form submital of fields is in no way th way i do it. alot of people do it like this but these applications have a class that read in field values and submit to the db through the class. i wonder how it does it. it was alot of work to go through and find out how their doing it.

Comment: @sarmenhbbb: Maybe you want to have a look at the Zend Framework or Symfony. I guess the examples you found use a combination of ORM and some form framework. If you have to deal a lot with forms, it gets annoying some time. If you use a and least a form framework you could save a lot time ;) E.g. Zend Form: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html

Answer (score 2):

As Jonathan said, 100 fields in one form is way to much. But you can always build the SQL dynamically.

E.g:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  // allow only entries that are database fields
  $allow = array(/*whatever*/);

  $fields = array();
  $values = array();

  foreach($_POST as $field => $value) {
     if(in_array($field, $allow) {
        // Do correct output escaping etc. here !!
        $fields[] = $field;
        $values[] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
     }
  }

  mysql_query('insert into table(' . join(',', $fields) . ' values(' . join(',', $values) . ')');
}
```

This assumes that your form fields names are the same as your DB column names.

If, as Cyro says, `array_keys` and `array_values` preserve order, then this can be done even nicer:

```
function clean($value, $field, &$params) {
    if(in_array($field, $params['allow']) {
       // custom validation goes here
       $params['data'][$field] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  // allow only entries that are database fields
  $allow = array(/*whatever*/);

  $params = array('allow' => $allow, 'data' => array());

  array_walk($_POST, 'clean', $params);

  if(!empty($params['data'])) {
      mysql_query('insert into table(' . join(',', array_keys($params['data'])) . ' values(' . join(',', array_values($params['data'])) . ')');
  }
}
```

See [`array_walk`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Answer (score 1):

If your form contains over 100 fields, I'd worry much more about the client side than the server side. Consider using something like [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) to split the form up into multiple areas, separated using fieldsets, to enhance usability.

One way around the array issue would be to use something like PHP's [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function, but I wouldn't recommend this for security reasons, and because it wouldn't really make the data any easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of dealing with so many fields is to reduce the number of fields. No one wants to have to fill out scores of fields.

Failing that, [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) has much to offer by supporting [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). One thing are parameters, which (unlike your sample code) aren't vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). Parameters can also be used to more easily construct a query using values from an array.

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (surname, given_name, main_phone, ...) 
    VALUES (:fname, :lname, :phone, ...)");

$values = array()
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $values[':' + $key] = $val;
}
try {
    $query->execute($values);
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    ...
}
```

The list of column names can be defined elsewhere, or automatically generated, then `implode`d when creating the prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

If your form field names directly relate to your database table columns you can dynamically build your query from the $_POST array.  From your example you could do:

```
$allowed_fields = array('fname', 'lname', 'phone');
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  // if this isn't an expected field (user-injection) ignore it
  if(!in_array($key, $allowed_fields))
    continue;

  // do validation checks and data clean up here in a switch
  $data[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(`" . implode('`, `', array_keys($data)) . "`) VALUES('" . implode("', '", array_values($data)) . "')");
```

Really though, a form with 100+ fields is not something I would ever fill out and I don't believe I'm alone in that.  Consider breaking it up into multiple steps as others have suggested or try re-approaching your initial design.

Comment: Are you sure that `array_keys()` and `array_values()` preserve order? Couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: @Felix Yes, I've used them countless times and had no issues.

Comment: using column names as form input names discloses information and is thus a security risk. It's not considered best practice.