# Working around dynamic forms in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form with fields dynamically generated (Also with their Id's and names) by javascript. How do I workaround with them once submitted to a PHP file? For example, I like to display all values into another page, what's a good way to work with the `$_POST` array?

Comment: Provide some examples and we will be able to help you further.

Comment: possible duplicate of [form $_POST as an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260531/form-post-as-an-array)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    echo $name . ':' . $value;
}
```

something along those lines should be enough to get you started :-)

**EDIT** Corrected $POST to $_POST

Answer (score 2):

[`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) can be used to iterate over an array.